# Как реализовать на С++ свою автоматическую сборку мусора?

Tags: c++, графы, дерево, сборщик-мусора

Нужен простейший вариант на счетчиках ссылок, для следующего дерева классов:

```
struct AST {
string val;
vector<AST*> nest; void push(AST*); // nested tree elements
virtual string dump(int depth=0); string pad(int); // dump tree
};

struct Num:AST { Num(string); double val; string dump(int); };
struct Str:AST { Str(string); };
struct Op:AST { Op(string); };
struct Vector:AST { Vector(); }
```

Проблема заключается в попытке влоб реализовать вычисление на дереве:

```
AST glob("environment","global");
AST* AST::eval(AST*E=&glob) {
for (it = nest.begin(), e=nest.end(); it!=e ; it++)
    (*it) = (*it)->eval(E); // вот здесь водопадная утечка памяти
return this; }
```

Не уверен, что `shared_ptr` способен работать с **глобальными** структурами данных -- парсер строит в памяти глобальное дерево или граф, затем по нему бегает обработчик (или несколько параллельно, но это в перспективе), который этот граф перестраивает, индексирует, или строит новую часть сети обходя существующие связанные элементы. Это что-то из области реализации семантических сетей или [фреймов Минского](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)), для начала -- просто интерпретатор на деревьях с вычисляемыми атрибутами.

Comment: А std::shared_ptr и std::weak_ptr не подойдут?

Comment: Могу предложить два варианта "слежки" (простейший случай). 1. refcount - когда обьект не используется вы понижаете  refcount, если задействован - повышаете. При refcount 0 или -1 - очищает обьект. 2. вы ставите временную метку которую обновляете если обьект повторно используется, и при определённы условиях (например когда к-во обьёктов > 100) самый старый удаляете. в таком случае вы можете даже сделать массив прединициализированых обьектов и не делать каждый раз new.